# C++ code breaks into line and for the love of me I can't fix it

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, line-breaks

Basically my code is supposed to take input from the user about the runners of a marathon, and then display the 3 best times and have the ability to search and display any runner. Right now the code is still pretty bare-bones, but it should at least take the input it, organize the info in ascending order (winners function) and I was in the middle of writing the display function when I decided to compile the code to test, and then it all goes down hill. 
Basically when I have to input the name of the first runner, the code breaks into this line:

```
static void __CLRCALL_OR_CDECL assign(_Elem& _Left, const _Elem& _Right) _NOEXCEPT
{   // assign an element
    _Left = _Right;
}
```

First of all I have no idea what that means or why left = right, and second a friend ran my code on his machine and told me he encountered no errors.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#pragma once
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class race
{
private:

public:
    int timeH, timeM, timeS, timeT;
    int number;
    string name;

    void input();
};

int size;
race *runner = new race[size];
void input();
void winners();
void display();
int main(){


    input();
    winners();
    display();

    system("pause");
}
void input(){

    cout << "Indique la cantidad de corredores: ";
    cin >> size;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        cout << "Nombre del corredor ";
        cin >> runner[i].name;
        cout << "Numero del corredor # "<<i;
        cin >> runner[i].number;
        cout << "Tiempo del corredor # " << i << endl << "Indique cuantas horas tardo :";
        cin >> runner[i].timeH;
        runner[i].timeH = runner[i].timeH * 3600;
        cout << "Cuantos minutos: ";
        cin >> runner[i].timeM;
        runner[i].timeM = runner[i].timeM * 60;
        cout << "Cuantos segundos: ";
        cin >> runner[i].timeS;

        runner[i].timeT = runner[i].timeH + runner[i].timeM + runner[i].timeS;
    }

}
void winners(){

    race temp;
    int flag = 1;
    for (int j = 1; (j <= size) && flag; j++){

        flag = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size-1; i++){

            if (runner[i + 1].timeT < runner[i].timeT)
            {
                temp = runner[i];
                runner[i] = runner[i + 1];
                runner[i + 1] = temp;


                flag = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated.

Comment: And where in *your* code does it "break"? The problem is most likely not in the library code but in yours, so follow the call-stack up to your code, and tells us where that is (please *edit your question* to do it).

Comment: `cin >> size;`  Don't you think you're a little too late to get the size?  You've already allocated your `race` array with 0 elements.

Answer (score 3):

```
int size;
race *runner = new race[size];
```

That's a problem right there. You're allocating memory, but you haven't set `size` yet (that allocation runs *before* `main()` is invoked). That means you are doing `new race[0]` (because `size` is initialized to zero, since it's a global `int`). Ergo, the rest of your program is invoking undefined behavior, because `runner` is an empty array, which you're trying to (illegally) access.

You're also leaking memory, as you never `delete []` the memory you allocate with `new []`. I suggest heading [Joachim's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28574363/1287251) and using `std::vector`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this:

```
int size;
race *runner = new race[size];
```

Uninitialized global variables are *zero* initialized, so `size` will be initialized to zero, so you're allocating a zero-sized array which means any access to the array will be out of bounds and lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

There are two ways of solving this:

1. Wait with the allocation until you *know* the size. (Not the solution I recommend.)
2. Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) which is a dynamically sized "array" type (the solution I do recommend).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but the array must be user controlled, and I was told that was there only way to do it. Is there another method?

Comment: @John Yes, use *`std::vector`*, then you can add entries as needed.